# Adding link to appended table row using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Using jQuery, I append rows to a table and each row contains an anchor tag. The jQuery is then supposed to add in a link to the anchor tag but the links do not show up. The other data (e.g., date, location) fills in fine so I'm not sure what the issue is.

jQuery:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
  ...
  $('.recent-reports tbody').append('<tr><td></td><td></td><td><a class="js-pdf-download" href="">Download</a></td></tr>');
  $('.recent-reports tbody tr:last').find('td').eq(0).text(date)
                                    .find('td').eq(1).text(location)
                                    .find('.js-pdf-download').attr("href", link)
  ...    
}
```

HTML:

```
<table class="recent-reports">
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Still no solution. Might this have to do with not being able to manipulate a class that was added in dynamically with jQuery?

Comment: Why append something and then look it up? Just add the data directly

Comment: The data to be filled in is being retrieved from a database and the number of table rows depends on the number of records in the db.

Comment: Or do you mean something like this? .append('<tr><td>' + date + '</td></tr';) etc...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Johann found a fix while simplifying my code at the same time. Rather than appending a row to the table and *then* adding in the data, I now append the row *with* the data in one fell swoop.

```
$('.recent-reports tbody').append('<tr><td>' + date + '</td><td>' + location + '</td><td><a class="js-pdf-download" href="' + link + '" target="_blank">Download</a></td></tr>')
```

Also, a clumsier solution, but one that would have been in line with my original approach:

```
 ...
  $('.recent-reports tbody tr:last').find('td').eq(0).text(date)
  $('.recent-reports tbody tr:last').find('td').eq(1).text(location)
  $('.recent-reports tbody tr:last').find('.js-pdf-download').attr("href", link)
  ...
```